# What is the Probability that the kth card dealt from a deck is a red ace.

Tags: probability

If you deal one card at a time from a shuffled deck,  what is the probability that a red ace will first appear on the k th card?  Example- the probability that a red ace will first appear on the first card dealt is 2/52.  If k=10, what is the probability that a red ace will first appear when you deal the 10th card. Give the expression for arbitrary k.

Comment: The title question is different from the body question. The probability that the $52$nd card dealt is a red ace is $2/52.$ The probability that a red ace will ***first*** appear on the $52$nd card is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{52}2$ possible locations for the two red aces, all equally likely. You are asking about the event that one of two red aces is in the $k^{\text{th}}$ position, and the other one is in one of the $52-k$ subsequent positions. The probability of that is
$$\frac{52-k}{\binom{52}2}=\frac{52-k}{1326}.$$

Comment: An elegant solution.  I calculated the probability as $$\frac{\binom{50}{k - 1}}{\binom{52}{k - 1}} \cdot \frac{2}{52 - (k - 1)}$$ by finding the probability that a red ace was not selected among the first $k - 1$ cards and that a red ace was selected with the $k$th card.  Of course, it reduces to the expression you found.

Comment: bof's  succinct solution can be put  into elementary words.
The Probability that the first red ace shows up on the kth
card,  is proportional to (52-k), the available places the
second red ace can appear. i.e.  Prob of k = Cx(52-k) where
C is the constant of proportionality.
The sum of probabilities from k=1 to k=51   adds up to one.
    1=  sum over k = 1 to k=51 of  C x ( 52-k )
 The sum of k from k=1 to k=51  is equal to  (51x52)/2, 
so  C is the inverse of  51x (52 -52/2)  = 51x26 =1326 and
the probability sought  is   (52-k)/1326.

Answer (score 0):

For a formal proof I would use the hypergeometric distribution. The event you are interested in can be stated as

after k cards exactly one red ace was drawn, but no red ace was drawn among the first k-1 cards.

Using the formula

$$P(A \backslash B) = P(A) - P(A \cap B)$$

one can compute the probability of interest by calculating the probability for the events

after k cards exactly one red ace was drawn

and

after k-1 cards exactly one red ace was drawn and the k-th card was not a red ace.